# SRAM force upgrade from compact to standard 53-39

Tags: sram

I have a SRAM force compact crankset and I want to change it to a standard 53-39.
Is it possible and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and fairly easy. You'll need to purchase a new chain in either route you go. You will also need to move and readjust your front derailleur.

You can purchase a new standard crankset and swap it out. You'll need to ensure that you get the correct version to match the bottom bracket which is most likely either BB30 or GXP and should be detailed on either your frame documentation on the frame itself or the bottom bracket.

If you do not have experience with this, you might want to bring it to a shop to actually switch out your cranks if you go that route to ensure proper installation.

Comment: New chain rings 39/53 will not fit on a compact crank arm as the dcb is larger.  You will have to buy a new chain set to fit your existing BB and increase the chain length with the excess chain from the one fitted.

Comment: @Kipper, after about 5 minutes of searching, I've found rings by TA Specialties for 110 bcd that are compatible with 10 speed setups: http://harriscyclery.net/product-list/parts-1400/chainrings-1405/chainrings-110-mm-bcd-1279/